# passing event data dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please refer below HTML

```
<div class="Icon">
                <span>
                        <img src=""/>
                    </span>

            </div>
```

I am adding class `"bootstrap-modal"`  dynamically to above IMG tag when it is clicked.

```
$(".Icon img").on("click", function (e) {
            var data="some object";     
            $(this).addClass("bootstrap-modal");
    });
```

Then i have one more click event for bootstrap-modal class like below

```
$(document).on('click',"bootstrap-modal" function (e,data) {

//here i need to get data object 
});
```

how to pass data object from img click event to bootstrap-modal click event?

That means I need to get some values from previous click handler ? 
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save it in `data`:

```
$('.Icon img').on('click', function(e) {
    var data = 'some object';
    $(this).addClass("bootstrap-modal").data('test', data);
});

$('.Icon').on('click', '.bootstrap-modal', function(e, data) {
    var data = $(this).data('test');
});
```

**FYI:** Since you use the newest version of jQuery, you'd better use `on` method with event delegation instead of deprecated `live`. Here `.Icon` is supposed to be a static parent element of `.bootstrap-modal`.

Comment: If he has .on in one event handler he obviously has .on available in the other

Comment: @VisioN  Thanks .
i dont want to use data-attribute concept.because it will add attribute to that element. i don't want this behavior?  any other way ?

Comment: @mplungjan `:D` haven't noticed that! I will update the answer then.

Comment: @SivaRajini Who said that `.data()` method will add the attribute to the element? It will not.

Comment: @SivaRajini Forget about data attributes. `.data()` method can set any data for any element internally. You may store arrays, objects, strings, whatever.

Comment: @Vision Thanks its worked. then what is the difference between data-attribute and this ?